# How do I add this working swipe delete functionality to a new appended list item?

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-mobile, append, swipe

I want to have the common mobile swipe delete functionality seen here http://andymatthews.net/code/swipebutton/  I downloaded the source, and butchered my own version out of it.  It works fine and here is my html:

```
<div class="accounts">    
<div id="CreditCards">
            <ul id="swipeMe">
                <li ><a href="#">This works</a></li>
                <li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">This works<</a></li>
                <li data-swipeurl="#"><a href="#">This works<</a></li>
                <li >This works too</li>        
            </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

And than here is my html that takes in credit card info to add to the list:

```
  <div class= "addCC">        
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <form id ="ccForm">
            <input type="password" name="credit_card_number" id="credit_card_number" value="" placeholder="Credit Card Number">
            <input type="password" name="security_code" id="security_code" value="" placeholder="Security Code">
            <input type="date" name="expiration_date" id="expiration_date" value="" placeholder="Expiration Date">
            <input type="password" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name On Card">
            <input type="password" name="street_address" id="street_address" value="" placeholder="Street Address">
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="" placeholder="City">
            <input type="number" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" value="" placeholder="Zip Code">

            <button type="button" class="submitCC" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS that appends a new Credit Card to the existing list:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.submitCC').click(function(){
    var creditcard = $('#credit_card_number').val();
    $('.accounts  #swipeMe').append('<li><a href="#">' + creditcard + '</a></li>');
    $('#ccForm').slideUp();

});
```

And here is the JS involved with the plugin:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        // attach the plugin to an element
        $('#swipeMe li').swipeDelete({
            btnTheme: 'e',
            btnLabel: 'deleteniko',
            btnClass: 'aSwipeButton',
            click: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $(e.target).attr('href');
                $(this).parents('li').slideUp();
                $.post(url, function(data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                });
            }
        });

        $('#swipeMe li:nth-child(n)').on('click', function(){
            $(this).trigger('swiperight')
        });

    });
```

And finally here is the entire plug in:

```
(function($){

$.fn.swipeDelete = function(o){

    o = $.extend( {}, $.fn.swipeDelete.defaults, o );

    return this.filter('#swipeMe li').each(function(i, el){
        var $e = $(el);
        var $parent = $(el).parent('ul');

        $e.on(o.direction, function ( e ) {

            // reference the current item
            var $li = $(this);
            var cnt = $('.ui-btn', $li).length;

            // remove all currently displayed buttons
            $('div.ui-btn, .' + o.btnClass, $parent).animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 200, function(e) {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            // if there's an existing button we simply delete it, then stop
            if (!cnt) {
                // create button
                var $swipeBtn = $('<a>' + o.btnLabel + '</a>').attr({
                                    'data-role': 'button',
                                    'data-mini': true,
                                    'data-inline': 'true',
                                    'class': (o.btnClass === 'aSwipeBtn') ? o.btnClass : o.btnClass + ' aSwipeBtn',
                                    'data-theme': o.btnTheme,
                                    'href': $li.data('swipeurl')
                                })
                                .on('click tap', o.click);

                // slide insert button into list item
                $swipeBtn.prependTo($li).button();
                $li.find('.ui-btn').hide().animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 200);

                //override row click
                $('div a:not(' + o.btnClass + ')', $li).on('click.swipe', function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).unbind('click.swipe');
                    $li.removeClass('ui-btn-active').find('div.ui-btn').remove();
                });


            }

        });

    });
};



$.fn.swipeDelete.defaults = {
    direction: 'swiperight',
    btnLabel: 'Delete',
    btnTheme: 'e',
    btnClass: 'aSwipeBtn',
    click: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('li').slideUp();
    }
};
```

}

I apologize for all the code.  It appends just fine, and the delete works well on the html elements, but any newly appended list items don't have the delete functionality.  Any ideas why?